# how to make short row in listVIew on android app

Tags: java, android

i want to create view row in listView 
linked to the right or left and did not catch whole row

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"
     android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
     android:paddingRight="50dp"
  /> 
<!-- <stroke android:width="0.1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/> -->
<corners

    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
<padding
    android:left="50dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set margin-left or margin-right property with the main layout of your row view

Answer (score 0):

activity_list_view_android_example.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          padding-left="20dp" >
     </ListView>
```

> instead use padding-left to set short rows for list

Comment: Not all the listView to specific lines